# pcl/conversion.h not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had again a similar error : " pcl/conversions.h any file of this kind" However the file is in the folder pcl/src/conversions.h
But this time even if I add pcl in find-package and in generate_message the error remain

**This is the CMakeLists**   :

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(costmap_2d)


find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  dynamic_reconfigure
  eigen
  geometry_msgs
  laser_geometry
  map_server
  map_msgs
  nav_msgs
  pcl
  pcl_ros
  rosbag
  rosconsole
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  tf
  visualization_msgs
  voxel_grid
  message_generation
  
)


find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)
include_directories(
    include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_definitions(${EIGEN_DEFINITIONS})


add_message_files(
    DIRECTORY msg
    FILES
    VoxelGrid.msg
)

generate_messages(
    DEPENDENCIES
        std_msgs
        geometry_msgs
    map_msgs
    
    
        
)

# dynamic reconfigure
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  cfg/Costmap2D.cfg
  cfg/ObstaclePlugin.cfg
  cfg/GenericPlugin.cfg
  cfg/InflationPlugin.cfg
  cfg/VoxelPlugin.cfg
)



include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS
        include
        ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    LIBRARIES costmap_2d
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
        dynamic_reconfigure
        geometry_msgs
        laser_geometry
        nav_msgs
        pcl_ros
        roscpp
        sensor_msgs
        std_msgs
        tf
        voxel_grid
    DEPENDS
        PCL
        Eigen
        Boost
)


add_library(costmap_2d
  src/array_parser.cpp
  src/costmap_2d.cpp
  src/observation_buffer.cpp
  src/layer.cpp
  src/layered_costmap.cpp
  src/costmap_2d_ros.cpp
  src/costmap_2d_publisher.cpp
  src/costmap_math.cpp
  src/footprint.cpp
  src/costmap_layer.cpp
)
add_dependencies(costmap_2d geometry_msgs_gencpp)
target_link_libraries(costmap_2d
  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_library(layers
  plugins/footprint_layer.cpp
  plugins/inflation_layer.cpp
  plugins/obstacle_layer.cpp
  plugins/static_layer.cpp
  plugins/voxel_layer.cpp
  src/observation_buffer.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(layers
  costmap_2d
)

add_dependencies(costmap_2d costmap_2d_gencfg)
add_dependencies(layers costmap_2d_gencfg)
add_dependencies(costmap_2d costmap_2d_gencpp)

add_executable(costmap_2d_markers src/costmap_2d_markers.cpp)
add_dependencies(costmap_2d_markers visualization_msgs_gencpp)
target_link_libraries(costmap_2d_markers
    costmap_2d
    )

add_executable(costmap_2d_cloud src/costmap_2d_cloud.cpp)
add_dependencies(costmap_2d_cloud sensor_msgs_gencpp)
target_link_libraries(costmap_2d_cloud
    costmap_2d
    )

add_executable(costmap_2d_node src/costmap_2d_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(costmap_2d_node
    costmap_2d
    )

## Configure Tests
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  # Find package test dependencies
  find_package(rostest REQUIRED)
  find_package(gtest)

  # Add the test folder to the include directories
  include_directories(test)

  include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  link_directories(${GTEST_LIBRARY_DIRS})

  # Create targets for test executables
  add_executable(costmap_tester EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/costmap_tester.cpp)
  add_dependencies(tests costmap_tester)
  target_link_libraries(costmap_tester costmap_2d ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

  add_executable(footprint_tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/footprint_tests.cpp)
  add_dependencies(tests footprint_tests)
  target_link_libraries(footprint_tests costmap_2d ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

  add_executable(obstacle_tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/obstacle_tests.cpp)
  add_dependencies(tests obstacle_tests)
  target_link_libraries(obstacle_tests costmap_2d layers ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

  add_executable(static_tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/static_tests.cpp)
  add_dependencies(tests static_tests)
  target_link_libraries(static_tests costmap_2d layers ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

  add_executable(inflation_tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL test/inflation_tests.cpp)
  add_dependencies(tests inflation_tests)
  target_link_libraries(inflation_tests costmap_2d layers ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})

  catkin_download_test_data(${PROJECT_NAME}_simple_driving_test_indexed.bag
    http://download.ros.org/data/costmap_2d/simple_driving_test_indexed.bag
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/test
    MD5 61168cff9425b11e093ea3a627c81c8d)
  catkin_download_test_data(${PROJECT_NAME}_willow-full-0.025.pgm
    http://download.ros.org/data/costmap_2d/willow-full-0.025.pgm
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/test
    MD5 e66b17ee374f2d7657972efcb3e2e4f7)

  add_rostest(test/footprint_tests.launch)
  add_rostest(test/inflation_tests.launch)
  add_rostest(test/obstacle_tests.launch)
  add_rostest(test/simple_driving_test.xml)
  add_rostest(test/static_tests.launch)

  catkin_add_gtest(array_parser_test test/array_parser_test.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(array_parser_test costmap_2d)
endif()

install( TARGETS
    costmap_2d_markers
    costmap_2d_cloud
    costmap_2d_node
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(TARGETS
    costmap_2d
    layers
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
)

install(FILES costmap_plugins.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

**This is the package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>costmap_2d</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The costmap_2d package</description>

  <!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag --> 
  <!-- Example:  -->
  <!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> -->
  <maintainer email="lempereur@todo.todo">lempereur</maintainer>


  <!-- One license tag required, multiple allowed, one license per tag -->
  <!-- Commonly used license strings: -->
  <!--   BSD, MIT, Boost Software License, GPLv2, GPLv3, LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3 -->
  <license>TODO</license>


  <!-- Url tags are optional, but mutiple are allowed, one per tag -->
  <!-- Optional attribute type can be: website, bugtracker, or repository -->
  <!-- Example: -->
  <!-- <url type="website">http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d</url> -->


  <!-- Author tags are optional, mutiple are allowed, one per tag -->
  <!-- Authors do not have to be maintianers, but could be -->
  <!-- Example: -->
  <!-- <author email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</author> -->


  <!-- The *_depend tags are used to specify dependencies -->
  <!-- Dependencies can be catkin packages or system dependencies -->
  <!-- Examples: -->
  <!-- Use build_depend for packages you need at compile time: -->
  <!--   <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend> -->
  <!-- Use buildtool_depend for build tool packages: -->
  <!--   <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend> -->
  <!-- Use run_depend for packages you need at runtime: -->
  <!--   <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend> -->
  <!-- Use test_depend for packages you need only for testing: -->
  <!--   <test_depend>gtest</test_depend> -->
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>dynamic_reconfigure</build_depend>
  <build_depend>eigen</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>laser_geometry</build_depend>
  <build_depend>map_server</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl_ros</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rosbag</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rosconsole</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>tf</build_depend>
  <build_depend>visualization_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>voxel_grid</build_depend>
  <build_depend>map_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>pcl</build_depend>
 
  <run_depend>dynamic_reconfigure</run_depend>
  <run_depend>eigen</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>laser_geometry</run_depend>
  <run_depend>map_server</run_depend>
  <run_depend>nav_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl_ros</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rosbag</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rosconsole</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>tf</run_depend>
  <run_depend>visualization_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>voxel_grid</run_depend>
  <run_depend>map_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>pcl</run_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- You can specify that this package is a metapackage here: -->
    <!-- <metapackage/> -->

    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187249/pcl/conversion.h-not-found/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
add pcl in build and run depend in package.xml, please also post package.xml if possible.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
I already added it, and it doesn't work

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
add pcl_conversions to find_package catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS and in package.xml. also put the error your getting in question.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
the screenshot of the error is this : "/navigation/costmap_2d/src/observation_buffer.cpp:41:29: erreur fatale: pcl/conversions.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminée.
make[2]: *** [navigation/costmap_2d/CMakeFiles/costmap_2d.dir/src/observation_buffer.cpp.o] Erreur 1"

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
it is in french and says that there any file or folder of this type

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
check rosdep check costmap_2d and do rosdep install costmap_2d to install dependencies.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
it says cannot locate rosdep definition for voxel_grid  and system dependencies have not been satisfied apt ros_groovy_map_msgs

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
do rosdep install costmap_2d and check

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
When I do rosdep install it says Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource cosmap_2d and then when I same error remain

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
do "rosdep update" and try installing.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
Sorry doesn't work, I still had the same error

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
are you using hydro ? if yes can you check if voxel_grid is present in /opt/ros/hydro/share path ?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
No I'm using groovy, and ubuntu 12.04

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
you can check if its available in /opt/ros/groovy/share

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
No it is not present in the folder

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
SORRY it is present in /opt/ros/groovy/share/doc/pcl-1.6/tutorials/source/voxel_grid

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
are you trying to build costmap_2d in groovy with source from hydro ?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
No I don't think so. Why do you think that?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
can you post the path of  pcl/src/conversions.h

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
I was checking hydro cmakelits.txt and package.xml and thought your modifying hydro code.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
So what should I do?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
can you post the path of pcl/src/conversions.h

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
catkin_ws/src/navigation/pcl/src/conversions.h

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
include the file like  #include "./navigation/pcl/src/conversions.h" also post how you have added headerfiles in .cpp file.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
#include <sensor_msgs/PointField.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include "pcl/point_cloud.h"
#include "pcl/ros/point_traits.h"
#include "pcl/ros/for_each_type.h"

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
#include "pcl/exceptions.h"
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <./navigation/pcl/src/conversions.h>

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
Is this that you asked? The header of the conversion.h file?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
yes, now can you build and paste complete error here. use http://pastebin.com/

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-21**:
http://pastebin.com/s2duDiKw

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-21**:
check this http://pastebin.com/hyis1kBF

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-22**:
Sorry I can't the paste have been remove, can you please resend me

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-22**:
sorry, check now http://pastebin.com/gDpReip1

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-22**:
No it has been again remove

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-22**:
i dont know its getting removed it put never expire http://pastebin.com/jzKWNtWr  I got know why check url and remove < / p > to get it.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-22**:
Sorry it doesn't work. I still have the same error,  it can't ffound the pcl/conversions.h

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-23**:
I really need some help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot depend on "voxel_grid". In groovy, this is not a catkin package, but a rosbuild pacakge. You cannot depend on a rosbuild package from a catkin package. This is likely why rosdep is not happy. Maybe the other errors are a consequence.

Is there a good reason why you must use groovy and not hydro? It seems like you are trying to do things that are better supported on hydro.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1